# Updating table SQlite

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def update_employee_table(self,ids,username, password, first_name, last_name,age, phone_number, department, city, address):
    self.connect()
    print(self)
    self.c.execute("UPDATE employee SET (username,password,first_name,last_name,age,phone_number,department,city,address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE id = ?",(username, password, first_name, last_name,age, phone_number, department, city, address),(ids))
    self.commit()
```

i am trying to update a table by the id and insert the values that i have passed to the function , the syntax of the update confuses me a little and i get this error : TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include the variable `ids` inside the tuple that you pass as the 2nd argument of `execute()` and not as a 3d argument.
Also, the `UPDATE` statement is syntactically wrong as it is written with `VALUES`.
Write it like this:

```
sql = """
UPDATE employee 
SET (username,password,first_name,last_name,age,phone_number,department,city,address) =  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
WHERE id = ?
"""
self.c.execute(sql, (username, password, first_name, last_name, age, phone_number, department, city, address, ids))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)